# A strange SQL Query maybe using sum?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm looking to get some sql help. Here is an example of what my table has:

```
username  |  dataout(MB)  | datain(MB)`|  sessiontime
Dude      |  1000         | 500        |  2016-02-24 07:30:00
Dude      |  2500         | 3000       |  2016-01-31 07:30:00
```

What Im looking to get out:

```
username  |  data(MB) (all data counted together)  |
Dude      |    7000                                |
```

My Sql looks like this:

```
$allusers = db('DataBase')
        ->table('userinfo')
        ->join('radcheck', 'radcheck.username', '=', 'userinfo.username')
        ->join('pricing', 'pricing.pkg_id', '=', 'userinfo.PAKKET')
        ->join('radacct', 'radacct.username', '=', 'userinfo.username')
        ->select('pricing.price',
            'pricing.Tusage',
            'userinfo.RKNR',
            'userinfo.MEMO',
            'userinfo.DTORDER',
            'radacct.dataout',
            'radacct.datain')
        ->where('radcheck.active', '=', 1)
        ->where('radcheck.enabled', '=', 1)
        ->where('radacct.acctstarttime', '>', $monthStart)
        ->where('radacct.acctstarttime', '<', $monthEnd)
        ->get();
```

Thank You in advance.

Here is what I get out with the query:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjdQU.jpg)

The Problem is all of those Arrays are for the same user (RKNR) and I need one array with all the datain and out in one.

Comment: and your current code outputs what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT   username,
         SUM(dataout + datain) AS total_data
FROM     .... (insert tables/join over here)
GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to get the sum of `datain` and `dataout` by `username`:

```
SELECT username, SUM(dataout) + SUM(datain) AS data FROM tablename WHERE username = 'username';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to knn. I used that SQL as a ->selectRaw. And it worked perfect.
For Future reference this is how it turned out to look:

```
$allusers = db('radius')
        ->table('userinfo')
        ->join('radcheck', 'radcheck.username', '=', 'userinfo.username')
        ->join('pricing', 'pricing.pkg_id', '=', 'userinfo.PAKKET')
        ->join('radacct', 'radacct.username', '=', 'userinfo.username')
        ->select('pricing.price',
            'pricing.Tusage',
            'userinfo.RKNR',
            'userinfo.MEMO',
            'userinfo.DTORDER')
        ->selectRaw(' SUM(acctinputoctets) + SUM(acctoutputoctets) AS TotalOctets')
        ->where('radcheck.active', '=', 1)
        ->where('radcheck.enabled', '=', 1)
        ->where('radacct.acctstarttime', '>', $monthStart)
        ->where('radacct.acctstarttime', '<', $monthEnd)
        ->get();
```